# What would be a more performant way of solving this problem with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Had a coding challenge to do.

The question was to write a function which returns an arbitrary higher number than N which ends in 0.

My solution was:

```
function solution(N) {
    for (let n = N +1; n <= N + 10; n++) {
        if (n % 10 === 0) return n;
    }
}
```

Comment: please add the upper border. what means *could*?

Comment: I think your solution is still not too bad, it will have a max of 10 iterations, so it has a constant time complexity of O(1).

Comment: Your solution doesn't work for N=2.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just divide and use `Math.ceil`:

```js
const solution = (n) => Math.ceil((n+1)/10) * 10 

console.log(solution(49))
console.log(solution(40))
console.log(solution(41))
console.log(solution(0))
console.log(solution(-1))
console.log(solution(-11))
```

Comment: Nice one! short and simple. Love it. Too late for me, but just love to see how other people approach the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is the fastest:

```
function solution(N) {
    return 1000000000;
}
```

Unless there was a rule against that, it seems to be a trick question!

**Just for fun:**

There is only one way to settle this! Running all `n` from 1 to 999999999 for each functions. I got this result:

@François Huppé solution: 2.884sec

@Mark Meyer solution: 3.25sec

@assoron solution: 3.79sec

@Sharon S solution: 8.824sec

```js
var t = Date.now();
for(var n = 0; n < 1000000000; n++){
    var res = solution1(n);
}
document.write('@François Huppé solution\'s: ' + ((Date.now() - t)/1000) + 'sec <br>');

var t = Date.now();
for(var n = 0; n < 1000000000; n++){
    var res = solution2(n);
}
document.write('@Mark Meyer solution\'s: ' + ((Date.now() - t)/1000) + 'sec <br>');

var t = Date.now();
for(var n = 0; n < 1000000000; n++){
    var res = solution3(n);
}
document.write('@assoron solution\'s: ' + ((Date.now() - t)/1000) + 'sec <br>');

var t = Date.now();
for(var n = 0; n < 1000000000; n++){
    var res = solution4(n);
}
document.write('@Sharon S solution\'s: ' + ((Date.now() - t)/1000) + 'sec <br>');



function solution1(n) {
    return 1000000000;
}
function solution2(n) {
    return Math.ceil((n+1)/10) * 10;
}
function solution3(n) {
    return n + (10 - n % 10);
}
function solution4(N) {
    for (let n = N +1; n <= N + 10; n++) {
        if (n % 10 === 0) return n;
    }
}
```

Comment: Might as well write it as `1E9`

Comment: François Huppé solution's: 2.854sec;
Mark Meyer solution's: 6.034sec;
assoron solution's: 3.527sec;
Sharon S solution's: 13.91sec; using an older Firefox version.

Answer (score 2):

I'd just concatenate a `'0'` onto the end, and cast to a Number:

```
const solution = n => Number(n + '0')
```

You could also just ignore the input and return the largest possible number (the largest possible *input* is .9999e9, so 1e9 will work for all inputs)

```
const solution = n => 1e9;
```

Comment: Is that faster than `* 10`?

Comment: One of the rules which I didn't add is that N can be from 1 to 999,999,999 but the solution returned can not be greater than 10^9. But I like your thinking. Will add it now.

Comment: Oh yeah, that makes a bit more sense, you could just do `*10` instead, for some reason I was thinking about strings

Comment: The input is guaranteed to be at least 1, luckily

Comment: haha like it, thinking outside the box. too late for me, just like to learn and see how people approach these things

Answer (score 2):

If you need arbitrary higher number multiple of 10.
the easiest approach is to multiply it by 10.

```
const solution = n => n * 10
```

Answer (score 2):

Without Math, using mod.

```js
const solution = n => n + 10 - n % 10

console.log(solution(57))
console.log(solution(23))
console.log(solution(1))
console.log(solution(221))
console.log(solution(9000))
```

For N being smaller than 10^9 you can always add an if to catch those numbers.

Comment: That's nice. I'm *pretty* sure you need division for the modulus though.

Comment: Yeah no idea how I came up with that, fixing it.

Comment: Why not switch the '+10` and `-n%10` around, such that you get `const solution = n => n - (n%10) + 10`. This would allow arbitary high numbers. While you could still get underflow, `%` may be weird in genral for negative numbers.

Comment: I am not following, could you give me a specific example of a situation you have in mind?

Answer (score 1):

Since noone have considered the problem of precision, then it is a reasonable assumption that the result must be inside the safe integers, so we can simply return the maximal safe enter:

```
const safe = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER-1
const solution = n => safe
console.log(solution(2))
```

Note that the result is precomputed, so we only need to load a constant from memory and return it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you need to work with negative numbers, but you can use this trick I thought of which will give you the next number higher than n which ends in 0:

```js
function solution(number) {
 var remainder = number % 10;
 if(remainder === 0) {
  return number + 10;
 } else {
  return number + (10 - remainder);
 }
}

console.log(solution(42));
console.log(solution(50));
console.log(solution(105));
```

Edit: solution by assoron uses the same logic, but is a one liner.

Answer (score 0):

```
function solution(n)
{
    return n % 10 ? n + (10 - n % 10) : n + 10;
}
```